# Understanding a continuity argument for the limit of contour integrals frequently used in complex integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, analysis, contour-integration

The technique used below appears frequently in Complex Analysis but I have difficulty formally proving the result. So we have a continuous function $f$ on some set including a contour as in $C^+$ below, and we approximate the integral of $\int_{C^+} f$ as the limit of $\int_{C_\epsilon^+}f$. All it says is that an easy continuity argument shows it. So essentially we need to prove that $$\vert\int_{C^+}f - \int_{C_\epsilon^+}f\vert<\epsilon$$ for any small $\epsilon>0$. The difference of the integrals would be a contour integral around another rectangle which is the difference between the two rectangles $C^+$ and $C_\epsilon^+$. I thought about using the maximal inequality of the contour integral, however, since the diameter of the rectangle would be $2(\epsilon + d)$, where $d$ is the length of the rectangle, it does not go to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$. How can I prove this easy continuity argument?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The crucial point is that the "long" sides of the difference rectangle are opposite so writing in terms of one of them you get a segment integral of $g(z+\epsilon)-g(z-\epsilon)$ for appropriate continuous $g$ and that goes to zero with $\epsilon$ by continuity of the integrand not by smallness of the segment

Comment: @Conrad Could you elaborate that argument please? I don't get why we would have integral of $g(z+\epsilon)-g(z-\epsilon)$ and how we can pass the limit inside the integral using continuity of the integrand.

Comment: Using the notation in the post excerpt, let $g$ the integrand and $\epsilon$ small so $z$ is not in the difference of the upper rectangles, hence $g$ continuous on said difference (which is the rectangle consisting of two small vertical sides while the horizontal sides are $\zeta = x, a\le x \le b, a,b$ fixed and $\zeta = x+i\epsilon, a\le x \le b$, sides taken opposite in the integral); so expliciting the integral on the difference rectangle, the vertical part is negligible by length, while the horizontal becomes $\pm \int_a^b({g(x)-g(x+i\epsilon))}dx$ and it goes to zero by continuity of $g$

Comment: @Conrad But without using dominated convergence(this is Riemann integral), how can we ensure the integral goes to zero since the integrand goes to zero?

Comment: it's just uniform convergence on a compact set, no need for dominated convergence  as $g(x+i\epsilon)-g(x)$ obviously converges uniformly to zero on $[a,b]$ as long as $g(\zeta)=\frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta-z}$ is continuous in a rectangle of the type $[a,b]$x$[0,\delta]$ for a small fixed positive $\delta$ and as noted that happens for any fixed $z$, once $\delta$ is chosen less than the imaginary part of $z$ here